# VBA and XML, bulding a function to deal with thousand of XML files

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I try to build up an excel function to study some XML files,  (those belong to a BI solution, and having tousand of XML files, best way seems to develop some macros to dig inside the files)

here a XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
  <name>PROC_A</name>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <name>Start</name>
      <type>SPECIAL</type>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Success</name>
      <type>SUCCESS</type>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>ST_1</name>
      <type>JOB</type>
      <filename>$/ST/PROC_ST_1.kjb</filename>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>DT_1</name>
      <type>JOB</type>
      <filename>$/DT/PROC_DT_1.kjb</filename>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>ST_2</name>
      <type>JOB</type>
      <filename>$/ST/PROC_ST_2.kjb</filename>
    </entry>
  </entries>
</job>
```

so, if I can call a funciton to get:

- makeMAGIC('myFile', 'getVALUE', '/name')   ->   PROC_A
- makeMAGIC('myFile', 'getNumNodes', '/entries/entry')   ->   5

and thats all I have succes to build it,

I would like to call the funcion also as :

- makeMAGIC('myFile', 'getEachVALUE', '/entries/entry~type')   ->   SPECIAL; SUCCESS, JOB, JOB, JOB
- makeMAGIC('myFile', 'getEachVALUE', '/entries/entry~filename')   ->   ; ; $/ST/PROC_ST_1.kjb; $/DT/PROC_DT_1.kjb; $/ST/PROC_ST_2.kjb

but not sure how shoud I go with the third "IF" of the code

so far, this is the function I have build:

```
Function makeMAGIC(file, instruction, key) As Variant


    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim strOUTPUT As String
    Dim firstNode As String
    Dim oDocXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    Set oDocXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
   
    FilePath = "C:\...\"
    FilePath = FilePath & file
   
    
    oDocXML.Load FilePath
    
    If Right(file, 4) = ".ktr" Then
        firstNode = "transformation"
    ElseIf Right(file, 4) = ".kjb" Then
        firstNode = "job"
    Else
        strOUTPUT = "UNKNOWN FILE"
        GoTo EndFunction
    End If
    

    If instruction = "getVALUE" Then
        Set xVALUE = oDocXML.SelectSingleNode("/" & firstNode & key)
        strOUTPUT = xVALUE.Text
    End If
    
    If instruction = "getNumNodes" Then
        Set xNodeList = oDocXML.SelectNodes("/" & firstNode & Split(key, "~")(0))
        auxI = 0
        For Each xNodeMember In xNodeList
            auxI = auxI + 1
        Next
    strOUTPUT = CStr(auxI)
    End If
    
    If instruction = "get_DOING" Then
        Set xNodeList = oDocXML.SelectNodes("/" & firstNode & Split(key, "~")(0))
        auxI = 0
        For Each xNodeMember In xNodeList

            'xDetailNode = xNodeList.SelectSingleNode("/" & Split(key, "~")(0))  -> not working
           
        Next
    strOUTPUT = CStr(auxI)
    End If
    

EndFunction:
 Set oDocXML = Nothing
 makeMAGIC = strOUTPUT
End Function
```

Comment: I wouldmake three different functions for getting values, numnodes or all-values.

Comment: You have `If instruction = "get_DOING" Then` but your example call is `makeMAGIC('myFile', 'getEachVALUE', '/entries/entry~type')`. There isn't any code to handle an instruction of `getEachVALUE`

Comment: @MAx , yes, indeed, I will ahve separate funcionts afterwards, but fors I need to know how to build up this part of the function

Comment: @barrowc. sotty, indeed a misstype, get_DOING should be indeeed get called getEachVALUE

Answer (score 0):

the "third if" would have to be:

```
If instruction = "getEachVALUE" Then
    Set xNodeList = oDocXML.SelectNodes("/" & firstNode & Split(key, "~")(0))
    auxI = 0
    For Each xNodeMember In xNodeList

        xDetailNode = xDetailNode & xNodeMember.text & ";"
       
    Next
strOUTPUT = CStr(xDetailNode)
End If
```

and is has to be called with something like

```
Call makeMAGIC("test.kjb", "getEachVALUE", "/entries/entry/filename")
```

or

```
Call makeMAGIC("test.kjb", "getEachVALUE", "/entries/entry/name")
```

I hope this works!
Max

Comment: .text  , seriously??  I fell so lame right now I am red as the red billard ball . I am trying later, THANKS A LOT

Comment: .text is responding me with all the nodes data  [Start Special; Success SUCCESS; ST_! JOB $...,kjb ; ...] and I would like to get only the ones from one of the attributes, lets say name = [Start; Success; ST_1; ...]

Comment: you have to call it correct:  
Call makeMAGIC("test.kjb", "getEachVALUE", "/entries/entry/filename")   
instead of entry-filename